# Header has incorrect capitalization

Tags: bug, formatting, design

It seems that on the main Cardano Beta site, the banner at the top of the page with the link to meta has the wrong capitalization.

How it looks on Chrome on my PC:
[image: Banner on Cardano]

Is this just the way it is supposed to be, or is this a formatting bug?

Comment: It's an old banner that is seen so infrequently that no one has really thought to update it to make it not look childish. Long, long ago lowercasing everything used to be the "style" around here. Glad that's over. Hopefully this can be easily fixed.

Comment: @animuson Great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Animuson's comment explains why the capitalization is wrong, but to address your question even further, let me suggest not to worry about it too much, since that banner will only be there during Private Beta (2-3 weeks) and then it will be gone permanently (you can take a look at the two most recent sites to have a Beta go live: Matter Modeling and Drones).

Comment: I see. This is the first Beta that I have participated on in SE, so I did not know if this header was going to be there through just the first few weeks or through the site's graduation. Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: No problem! Yea you can just take a look at the most recent Beta sites to see how things would look here after awhile (if we do get approved to move on to Public Beta!).